# SwiftUI updating @Binding value in NavigationLink(destination:label) causes destination to reappear

Tags: binding, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a weird issue, where I navigate to `EditView` and edit a state variable from `ContentView`. After that I dismiss `EditView` with `presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()`. The problem is, as soon as the view is dismissed, it reappears again.

I'm using XCode 12.4 and my iOS deployment target is set to 14.4

Observations:

- `EditView` doesn't reappear if the value isn't edited
- removing the changed value `Text("Value: \(title)")` >> `Text("Value")` from `ContentView` tree resolves the issue, but that obviously isn't a solution.
- moving the `NavigationLink` from `.toolbar` e.g.

```
    VStack {
        Text("Value: \(title)")
        NavigationLink(destination: EditView(title: $title)){
            Text("Edit")
        }
    }
```

also resolves the issue, but that seems like a hack. Besides, I'd like to keep using `.toolbar` because I like the `.navigationTitle` animation and I can't have a button in the upper-right corner of the screen if I have a navigation title without the toolbar.

Here's the full code:

```
    import SwiftUI

    struct ContentView: View {
        @State var title: String = "Title"
        @State var isActive: Bool = false
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                    
                Text("Value: \(title)")
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                            NavigationLink(destination: EditView(title: $title, isActive: $isActive), isActive: $isActive){
                                Text("Edit")
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct EditView: View {
        @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
        
        @Binding var title: String
        @Binding var isActive: Bool
        
        var body: some View {
            Button(action: {
                title = "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)"
    //            presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                isActive = false
            }){
                Text("Done")
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
```

As far as I can tell this is a `.toolbar` bug, and if it turns out that way I'll report it to Apple, but in the meantime, does anyone have a better solution  and/or explanation for this?

Cheers!

**EDIT:**

I updated the code with `isActive` value for the `NavigationLink`. It doesn't work when written like that, but uncommenting the commented out line makes it work. But that's quite hacky.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up 2 things `NavigationLink` will push the view on `stack`, just like `NavigationController` in swift. That’s why you can see back button after navigating to second view. When you hit back button, it will pop top most view out of `stack`. `presentationMode` is not needed , dismissing presented view will not pop it of the stack.

To present a view and dismiss it you can check below code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentViewsss: View {
    @State var title: String = "Title"
    @State var isPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Value: \(title)")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button(action: {
                            isPresented.toggle()
                        }){
                            Text("Edit")
                        }
                    }
                }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
            EditView(title: $title, state: $isPresented)
        })
    }
}

struct EditView: View {
   
    @Binding var title: String
    @Binding var state: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            title = "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)"
            state.toggle()
        }){
            Text("Done")
        }
    }
}
```

If you want `NavigationLink` functionality, you can just remove `presentationMode` code from second view, and keep `ContentView` as it is -:

```
struct EditView: View {
     //@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    
    @Binding var title: String
      
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            title = "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)"
            // presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }){
            Text("Done")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the thing is, i need to dismiss the view programmatically - when I press the 'done' button, and afaik presentationMode is the only way?

Comment: @EliseyOzerov didn’t get you. If you don’t want to use presentationMode to dismiss, you can also pass isPresented state property as binding to EditView, and toggle it back to false on done button.

Comment: I just tried that, but nothing happens. The interesting part is that if I try both at the same time, it works. But that's a hacky solution lol

Comment: @EliseyOzerov can you update your code with what you tried.

Comment: i cant use sheet modifier there because the code in ContentView is already in a sheet in my project - I updated the code btw

Comment: @EliseyOzerov It does seems like a bug.